# Playing video files from dropbox with videojs

Tags: video, dropbox, video.js

I'm playing video files from dropbox with [videojs](http://videojs.com/)

It works pretty well, but certain video files are not playing, seemingly randomly. All of the video files are h264 with aac audio so I'm really confused about what can cause the problem. The only thing I can think of so far is that the problematic videos usually are larger in file size with a higher resolution and bitrate. Some users have reported that when not serving the files from dropbox it works, but I can not confirm if that's 100% of the times or not, to circle Dropbox as the cause.

Dropbox has the ?dl=1 and ?raw=1 flags at the end of the links. Anyone know which one I should use? I first used raw but now switched to dl to see if it works better.

It seems like there is a redirect involved in the dropbox urls, can that have anything to do with it? The videos play on dropbox own videojs player if using the ?dl=0 flag, which makes it even stranger.

These are two errors I've seen:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (HTTP/2.0 403)

...

> VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could
>   not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because
>   the format is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Your '403' error code status is too generic to be able to guess what the underlying issue might be, as there are at least 20 subcodes (403.nn values)
for 403, each with their own specific cause.  For a list of all the various
403.nn codes, see the list here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

I've been down this road (referencing cloud-based video files for html5, and
the videojs viewer), and I too had various errors and issues when 
using H.264 video codec.

(I happen to use Google Cloud Platform to host my video files, rather than Dropbox, but I'm betting that your choice of which cloud-service to use is NOT
relevant to your issues.)

Luckily for me, I first ran tests using H.264 video-codec files LOCALLY
from our webserver BEFORE I moved to the next step of putting my video 
files over onto cloud-storage.  One major thing I learned is that, when 
using H.264 codec and running in Chrome browser under Windows, that 
playback 'worked mostly', but was jerky enough that it was NOT acceptable. 
(In all the other browsers, H.264 rendered fine.) Bottom line... it became a 'show-stopper' for me, for using H.264 for the video codec in my video files, because Chrome seems to be the most commonly used browser, for viewing webpages.

[ It may seem surprising that Google Chrome doesn't render H.264 reliably. But bear in mind that Google/Chrome has threatened to drop H.264 entirely, tho I'm
doubting that they'll ever go that far. My 'theory' of why they don't support
H.264 well, is that they've always been trying to push the industry to adopt
their alternative choice of VP8/VP9 for a video codec. ]

Long story short, after running some tests using VP8 video-codec and the
related/recommended audio-codec of 'vorbis' in my files, I found that
the only major browser(s) which do NOT support VP8 are Microsoft's browsers
(i.e. both 'IE' and their newer 'Edge' browser, and I'm willing to live
with not supporting MS's browsers in my webapps.)

Bottom-line: I now use videojs as the viewer and VP8/Vorbis for codecs in my
cloud-based video-files on my webpages, and everything is rendering 
'smooth-as-silk'.

[ As for a tool to use to transcode to VP8/Vorbis, I am use the cmd-line
tool 'FFmpeg'.  Once I got familiar with its cmd-line syntax, I found it
to be the most feature-rich transcoding tool available!  (Prior to that,
back when I still was going to H.264, I was using 'vlc' via its cmd-line, to transcode.  And, I'd also found,  for a GUI-based transcoder, that the 
Handbrake tool worked acceptably.) ]

As to your "ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED)", that return-code
DOES mean that the given browser does NOT support either your video 
or audio codec. (You didn't mention what browser and platform you were using
at the time, so, I AM curious as to what browser and platform you were testing against, when you got that error.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It still doesn't explain why it works for me, but not on my friend's network. I tried the exact same files from Dropbox on my friend's wifi and it didn't work, but on my wifi it worked (same laptop and browsers). I moved one of the files to my webserver and it worked on his network. He says he doesn't have any other issues with Dropbox, so that would mean that Dropbox is not blocked on his network.

Comment: I've been trying in Safari, Firefox and Chrome and I get that message in Chrome. Not sure if I've seen it in the other browsers as well. Even weirder, it plays in Chrome on my friend's network, but not Safari. I don't remember which error it was though. I see that this info is not really helpful. I'm confused. What I can confirm is that I have a h264 that is not working in Chrome on my network, but it is working in Safari and Firefox. I open the metatdata and I don't see much difference from any other h264 that is playing in Chrome.

Comment: What has been strange about this particular h264 is that I tried to re-encode it in both Mpeg Streamclip and Compressor and it takes forever, even for a 3 min video. I think it took 1-2 hours, so something is funky. Damaged file, missing some header or something? I've read that Chrome can't play a particular color space or something like that, but I don't know how to look that up. This is another lead that I'm looking up: [link](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/3351#issuecomment-304819267)

Comment: Hmm...I retract what I commented earlier (that Dropbox should work like other cloud-services).  I think that Dropbox may have limitations and attributes that isn't true of cloud-servers such as Google Cloud Platform and other pure cloud-servers. It would be helpful if you could post a full URL to your webpage so far, so we could inspect your html and javascript, etc.

Comment: I just got reported from a user that he switched to Amazon S3 and now all of his files plays without any problem! So I guess dropbox is having a cap/limit on HD/larger files or something? I can't share the page unfortunately, but just by the fact that switching to Amazon S3 helped him is a sign right. This should be documented somewhere.

Comment: >>>I can't share the page unfortunately  [ Hmm...does Dropbox support flagging a file to make it 'sharable with the whole world'?) I ask that, because on GoogleCloudPlatform, you must mark a video as 'public', if you all consumers to be able to view it via html-5.

Comment: >>>I can't share the page unfortunately [ Hmm...does Dropbox support flagging a file to make it 'shareable with the whole world'?) I ask that, because on GoogleCloudPlatform, you must mark a video as 'public', if you want all clients to be able to view it via html-5.]

Comment: Yes, they are all shared by everyone with the link. It just seems to be happening on large files with high resolution and/or bitrate, but I'm not sure.

Comment: When you used Google for hosting, did you use the "hashed" links? I'm having problems with virus scans and stuff making it impossible to direct link to the video files on Google. How did you get around that?

Comment: No, I use direct links.  (I'm not understanding how/why virus scans would cause any problem. ???)

Comment: Yes but there's no way of linking to a file with an .mp4 or .mov extension right? Google will make it their own hashed links. When I tried to link to a larger file google had me confirm a virus scan before I can play the file which made it impossible to embed. I also updated videojs to latest version and it seems to be working a little better. Still some funkiness, but usually if the file is full hd or over say 200mb.